# Unable to access fields in unnamed JSON array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax

I am fairly new to Javascript and JSON and I am trying to access the values in an unnamed JSON array. Since this is not my JSON file, I cannot alter it and give the array a name.
Here is the JSON Code:

```
[
  {
     "address":"0x51c3",
     "Balance":"2425"
  },{
     "address":"0x51c9",
     "Balance":"2425"
  }
]
```

Here is what I have attempted on the Javascript/AJAX front :

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta content = "text/html; charset = ISO-8859-1" http-equiv = "content-type">

      <script type = "application/javascript">
     function loadJSON(){
        var data_file = "http://localhost/balance.json";
        var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        try{
           // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari
           http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }catch (e){
           // Internet Explorer Browsers
           try{
              http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

           }catch (e) {

              try{
                 http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }catch (e){
                 // Something went wrong
                 alert("Your browser broke!");
                 return false;
              }

           }
        }

        http_request.onreadystatechange = function(){

           if (http_request.readyState == 4  ){
              // Javascript function JSON.parse to parse JSON data
              var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);

              // jsonObj variable now contains the data structure and can
              // be accessed as jsonObj.name and jsonObj.country.
              document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML = jsonObj[1].address;
              document.getElementById("Balance").innerHTML = jsonObj[1].Balance;
           }
        }

        http_request.open("GET", data_file, true);
        http_request.send();
     }


      </script>

   </head>

   <body>
      <table class = "src">


<tr><th>Address</th><th>Balance</th></tr>
         <tr><td><div id = "Address"></div></td>
         <td><div id = "Balance"></div></td></tr>
      </table>

      <div class = "central">
         <button type = "button" onclick = "loadJSON()">Update Details </button>
      </div>

   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: etherBalance is called Balance in the JSON and [1] will get the second of them

Comment: Apologies. I had changed the variable names before uploading this code. Nonetheless the problem still remains. Furthermore I am interested in retrieving the second set of values.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Any possibility to use jQuery Ajax?

Comment: Hi ! It seems to have worked. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your etherBalance is called Balance in the JSON and Balance in the DIV ID too.

Now the insertion works

```js
var data = '[  {     "address":"0x51c3",     "Balance":"2425"  },{     "address":"0x51c9",     "Balance":"2425"  }]';

function loadJSON() {
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);

    // jsonObj variable now contains the data structure and can
    // be accessed as jsonObj.name and jsonObj.country.
    document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML = jsonObj[1].address;
    document.getElementById("Balance").innerHTML = jsonObj[1].Balance;
}
```

```html
<table class="src">


  <tr>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Balance</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="Address"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="Balance"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="central">
  <button type="button" onclick="loadJSON()">Update Details</button>
</div>
```